# Send logs to file and syslog at the same time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, logging

Can you simultaneously send logs from the database to a file and to syslog?

Is it possible to set `log_destination = 'stderr', 'syslog'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but the syntax is

```
log_destination = 'stderr,syslog'
```